# Why doesn't this use of implicit casts work?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I've defined a generic class "`Lazy<T>`", for lazy evaluation and caching of the result of a delegate `Func<T>`.

I also define two implicit cast operators so I can create a `Lazy<T>` from a `Func<T>`s, and I can assign a `Lazy<T>` to a `T` (gets the `Value` of the `Lazy<T>`)

The idea is that you can pass around a `Lazy<T>` in place of an instance of `T`, but not do the work to calculate/retrieve the value until it is assigned to an actual instance of `T`.

```
// class Lazy<T>
// Encapsulates a value which can be retrieved when first accessed, 
// and is then cached.
class Lazy<T>
{
  private Func<T> _getter;
  private T _cached;
  private bool _isCached;

  // Get/set the getter delegate
  // that 'calculates' the value.
  public Func<T> Getter
  {
    get
    {
      return _getter;
    }
    set 
    {
      _getter = value;
      _cached = default(T);
      _isCached = false;
    }
  }

  // Get/set the value.
  public T Value
  {
    get 
    {
      if (!_isCached) 
      {
        _cached = Getter();
        _isCached = true;
        _getter = null;
      }
      return _cached;
    }
    set
    {
      _cached = value;
      _isCached = true;
      _getter = null;
    }
  }

  // Implicit casts:

  // Create a T from a Lazy<T>
  public static implicit operator T(Lazy<T> lazy) 
  {
    return lazy.Value;
  }

  // Create a Lazy<T> from a Func<T>
  public static implicit operator Lazy<T>(Func<T> getter)
  {
    return new Lazy<T> {Getter = getter};
  }
}
```

But this class doesn't work as I expected in one case, highlighted in the test app below:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    // This works okay (1)
    TestLazy(() => MakeStringList());

    // This also works (2)
    Lazy<string> lazyString = new Func<string>(() => "xyz");
    string s = lazyString;

    //This doesn't compile (3)
    //
    Lazy<IList<string>> lazyStrings = new Func<IList<string>>(MakeStringList);
    IList<string> strings = lazyStrings; //ERROR
  }


  static void TestLazy<T>(Func<T> getter)
  {
    Lazy<T> lazy = getter;
    T nonLazy = lazy;
  }

  private static IList<string> MakeStringList()
  {
    return new List<string> { new string('-', 10) };
  }
}
```

On the line marked with `//ERROR`, I get a compile error:

**error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `Lazy<System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

This error is confusing as there does exist an implicit cast from the source to the target type in question.
And, on the face of it, code chunk (3) is doing the same thing as (1)
Also, it differs from (2) only by the type used to specialize the Lazy.

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to convert to `IList<T>` implicitly, and `IList<T>` isn't encompassed by `IList<T>` (even though they're the same type) - only conversions to non-interface types are considered in encompassing. From section 6.4.3 of the C# 3.0 spec:

> If a standard implicit conversion
>   (§6.3.1) exists from a type A to a
>   type B, **and if neither A nor B are
>   interface-types**, then A is said to be
>   encompassed by B, and B is said to
>   encompass A.

In section 6.4.4, talking about user defined conversions, one of the steps is (emphasis mine):

> - Find the set of applicable user-defined and lifted conversion
>     operators, U.
>
> This set consists of the user-defined
>   and lifted implicit conversion
>   operators declared by the classes or
>   structs in D that convert from a type
>   encompassing S **to a type encompassed
>   by T**. If U is empty, the conversion is
>   undefined and a compile-time error
>   occurs.

`IList<T>` isn't encompassed by `IList<T>`, therefore this step fails.

The compiler will do "chained" implicit conversions in other scenarios though - so if you actually had a `Lazy<List<T>>` you *could* write:

```
object strings = lazyStrings;
```

works, because `List<T>` is encompassed by `object` (as both are classes, and there's a standard implicit conversion from `List<T>` to `object`).

Now as for *why* this is the case, I *suspect* it's to stop odd cases where you'd expect a reference conversion, but you would actually get the implicit conversion. Suppose we had:

```
class ListLazy : Lazy<IList<string>>, IList<string>
{
    // Stuff
}
...
Lazy<IList<string>> x = new ListLazy();
IList<string> list = x;
```

Which conversion should be used? There's an implicit *reference* conversion from the *actual* type to `IList<string>`... but the compiler doesn't know that, because the expression is of type `Lazy<IList<string>>`. Basically interfaces are awkward because they can show up later in the type hierarchy, whereas with a class you always know where you are, if you see what I mean. (Implicit conversions which involve two classes in the same hierarchy are prohibited.)

Comment: The weird thing is, the compile error still happens when List is replaced with IList (apart from where an instance of List is constructed and returned from a method that returns IList.

Comment: To be precise, now the compiler is complaining that there's no implicit cast from `Lazy<T>` to `T`, where `T==IList<string>`.
Even though I went and edited the question, it may be the case that your answer still holds, in which case I'll need to go an research what 'encompassing' is in order to understand the answer :)

Comment: But the point is you're still trying to convert to an *interface* - that's what it doesn't like.

Comment: I'll put the definition of encompassing into the answer... hold on.

Comment: @mackenir: Upvotes aren't as useful to me as accepting the answer, hint hint ;)

Comment: (should it now say Lazy<T> instead of List<T> throughout the answer?)

Comment: Indeed, your conjecture is spot on as usual Jon. The reason we disallow this kind of conversion on interfaces is because we never want to "replace" a cheap "built in" representation-preserving conversion with an expensive "user-defined" representation-changing conversion. A conversion to an interface should always simply be a type check to see if the interface is implemented.

Comment: Also, the "encompassing" stuff in this part of the spec is confusing, and not precisely what we actually implemented. I've been meaning to clean that up for some time now but never had the gumption to actually get through it.

Comment: @mackenir: No, it shouldn't say `Lazy<T>`, but it should use `IList<T>`... will edit.

Comment: @Eric: If you're ever on a sweep of confusing terminology, can you have a look at the bound/unbound, open/closed, constructed stuff for generics? It gives me headaches...

Comment: That stuff drives me nuts too. I always have to look it up to make sure that I'm getting it right. The fact that a non-generic type is BOTH a bound and an unbound type is frankly bizarre.

Comment: Still completely mystified by what 'encompassing' means.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be a little typo?

```
Lazy<List<string>> lazyStrings = new Func<List<string>>(MakeStringList);
IList<string> strings = lazyStrings; //ERROR
List<string> strings = lazyStrings; //OK
```

If you *do* want an IList<>, it's a 2-step conversion and I suppose the compiler doesn't want to get ahead of itself

```
IList<string> istrings = strings;
```

Comment: I think he wants to get an IList, and not a List.

Comment: Philippe, it isn't obvious, I was asking. But it does shift the question to "does the compiler do chained implicit conversions" or something.

Comment: +1 Implicit conversion requires that the types match up exactly. If you want an IList<string>, you can either change your method/delegate to return that from the start or use a second cast after the implicit cast to List<string>.

Comment: @Henk: that why I started my sentence by "I think". I wasn't completely sure either :)

Comment: They don't have to match up exactly - for instance, it would work fine with `object`, and if `List<T>` had any other base *classes* in the inheritance tree, those would be fine too.

Comment: Well spotted Henk! I originally had the types matching up, but that difference crept in somehow. I've fixed the question.
Unfortunately with the typo fixed and using IList everywhere, I still get the error.

Comment: @dahlbyk: nope, if you do "object o = lazyString;", it works fine. It's a matter of encompassing (see Jon answer).